# Azure Storage Directory Delete Error. ErrorCode: EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Detailed Error:

```
ERROR: This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint. ErrorCode: EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures
{"error":{"code":"EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures","message":"This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nRequestId:2ca07dd4-f01f-0049-5939-8a9044000000\nTime:2022-06-27T15:23:27.4308391Z"}}
```

The Command that I am using to Delete Blob Storage Directory:

```
az account set --subscription ${my_subscriptions[$i]}
az storage blob directory delete -c ${my_container[$i]} --account-name ${my_acc_name[$i]} -d ${my_source[$i]} --recursive
```

When I run "az storage account blob-service-properties show --account-name my_acc_name" I get following output:

```
{
  "automaticSnapshotPolicyEnabled": null,
  "changeFeed": {
    "enabled": false,
    "retentionInDays": null
  },
  "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
    "days": 7,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "cors": {
    "corsRules": []
  },
  "defaultServiceVersion": null,
  "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
    "allowPermanentDelete": false,
    "days": 7,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/0813acfc-11cd-493d-a7fc-8f230ce7bfb6/resourceGroups/team/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/myaccname/blobServices/default",
  "isVersioningEnabled": false,
  "lastAccessTimeTrackingPolicy": null,
  "name": "default",
  "resourceGroup": "team",
  "restorePolicy": {
    "days": null,
    "enabled": false,
    "minRestoreTime": null
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"
}
```

Can someone please explain me the above ERROR that I am getting and a solution to get rid off this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR: This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint. ErrorCode: EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures
{"error":{"code":"EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures","message":"This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nRequestId:2ca07dd4-f01f-0049-5939-8a9044000000\nTime:2022-06-27T15:23:27.4308391Z"}}
```

This error mentioning like you are enable soft delete for containers check whether its Enable

***Go to Azure portal -> storage account -> under data management -> data protection -> Disable soft delete as below***

[image]

```
   az storage blob service-properties delete-policy show
   --account-name *****
   --query 'enabled': false
```

To delete Blob Storage Directory try using below [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/directory?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
az storage blob directory delete -c MyContainer -d MyDirectoryPath --account-name MyStorageAccount
```

Storage account have Hierarchical Namespace enabled if yes, then the delete action can be atomic and immediately; if not, the operation is performed in batches and a continuation token could be returned.

For you Information check this [Ref1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/22775) & [Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/845340/delete-activity-in-adf-failing-to-delete-a-the-fil.html)